# How can I get rid of the "Close" button in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to give access to users to some Reports History (Reporting Services snapshots lists, under http://SEVERNAME//Reports/_layouts/ReportServer/ReportHistory.aspx?list={REPORTID} but they shouldn't access and navigate the Report Library to do so.
A Links List did the trick to direct the users to the reports and their reports history, the problem comes when they hit the Close button in the Reports History page: it redirects to an upper level (the Report Library users weren't supposed to see...)
Is there any way I can get rid of "Close" (or change its function)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to just go into 12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ReportServer and try and edit ReportHistory.aspx to get rid of the close link.

Answer (score 0):

Try and find a unique identifier of the close button or table cell that contains it and add a "visibility:hidden;" to it to hide from the user.

Don't go editing the out of the box files from Microsoft or your sharepoint will be in an unsupported state and woe will be yours!